# Scala official documentation Variances example code

Tags: scala

On http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/variances.html there is sample code

```
scala> class Stack[+A] {
 |   def push[B >: A](elem: B): Stack[B] = new Stack[B] {
 |     override def top: B = elem
 |     override def pop: Stack[B] = Stack.this
 |     override def toString() = elem.toString() + " " + Stack.this.toString()
 |   }
 |   def top: A = sys.error("no element on stack")
 |   def pop: Stack[A] = sys.error("no element on stack")
 |   override def toString() = ""
 | }
```

Then I defined two classes `B` and `C`

```
scala> class B(val d: Int)
scala> class C(override val d: Int) extends B(d)
```

I instantiate object `o1` and `o2` of type `B` and `C` respectively and push them onto a stack

```
scala> val o1 = new B(1)
o1: B = B@17046283

scala> val o2 = new C(2)
o2: C = C@2c767a52

scala> var s: Stack[B] = new Stack().push(o1)
s: Stack[B] = B@17046283

scala> s.top
res1: B = B@17046283

scala> s = s.push(o2)
s: Stack[B] = C@2c767a52 B@17046283

scala> s = s.pop
s: Stack[B] = B@17046283

scala> var s: Stack[B] = new Stack().push(o1)
s: Stack[B] = B@17046283

scala> s = s.push(o2)
s: Stack[B] = C@2c767a52 B@17046283

scala> s = s.push(o1)
s: Stack[B] = B@17046283 C@2c767a52 B@17046283
```

My question is why all the return types of `s` is `Stack[B]`. From the code it seems it could return `Stack[C]` for `push` calls? Sorry I'm a rookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` is covariant so a `Stack[C]` is a subtype of `Stack[B]` since `C` is a subtype of `B`. The signature of `push` means that if you push a supertype of `A`, you will receive a `Stack[Supertype]`. This means pushing a `B` onto a `Stack[C]` will return a `Stack[B]`:

```
val s = Stack[C]()
val bs: Stack[B] = s.push(new B(1))
```

However you are starting with a `Stack[B]`, so pushing a `C` will not return a `Stack[C]` since the stack could contain instances of `B`. You could push a supertype of `B` however:

```
val as: Stack[Any] = s.push(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`B >: A` means that `B` is a *supertype* of `A` (including A)

Effectively what this means is that when you have a `Stack[B]` and try to `push` something of type `A` to it, the compiler will try to find the most specific common supertype between the two.

Since `C` is a *subtype* of `B`, the most common supertype between C and B is `B`.